# Django - ImportError after Installing Angular and React

Tags: python, django, importerror

My Django Server was working perfectly but after installing Angular and React, my Django Server stopped working and started giving following error:
I have already researched a lot but unable to resolve error, pls help...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LM\dj\policyboss\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\LM\dj\policyboss\manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'policyboss.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Environment Variable]

Comment: use `pip list` in cmd and see if it's there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved error after 2 days of struggle by simply Uninstalling Python and then Reinstalling it again.

I think i had python installed in 2 locations which was causing some error, once i uninstalled it and then reinstalled it, now it is in 1 location only and finally started working.